# UWP keep Flyout open in designer for editing

Tags: uwp, flyout

Can you suggest me any workaround to keep the flyout open during designing?

For example (simplified):

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Flyout x:Key="FlyoutBoardSelection" Placement="Bottom" FlyoutPresenterStyle="{StaticResource FlyoutStyleDefault}" >
        <Textblock Text="I wannabe visible"/>
    </Flyout>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleDefault}" Content="OpenFlyout" Flyout="{StaticResource FlyoutBoardSelection}"/>
</Grid>
```

It's working well runtime but I only can designing it blindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing you can do is to put the content of the flyout on the page temporarily, design it there and then put it back into the flyout.

Even better solution would be to create a new `UserControl` which you could design separately and then put inside of the `Flyout`.

Right-click your project, select `Add -> New File`, there choose `User Control` and name it (like `BoardSelectionFlyoutContent`). This will create a `xaml` and `xaml.cs` files where you can design the `Flyout`'s content with full designer support.

Once you are done, you first add the namespace to XAML references on the top of your page:

```xml
xmlns:local="using:TheNamespaceOfYourControl"
```

And then use it inside the `Flyout`:

```cs
<Flyout x:Key="FlyoutBoardSelection" Placement="Bottom" 
        FlyoutPresenterStyle="{StaticResource FlyoutStyleDefault}" >
    <local:BoardSelectionFlyoutContent />
</Flyout>
```